# I have an error to get messages(gmail)

Tags: c#

I have problems in this line `xdoc.LoadXml(response)` and
I want to get my message with this code with in C#:

```
WebClient objclient = new WebClient();    
string response = null;    
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
try
{
    objclient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(log.Trim(), pass.Trim());
    response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(objclient.DownloadData("http://mail.google.com/mail/mail/feed/atom"));
    response = response.Replace("<feed version=\"0.3\" xmlns=\"http://purl.org/atom/ns#\">", "<feed>");
    xdoc.LoadXml(response); //Load xml file
    if(mailcount > 0)
    {
        emailfrom = new string[mailcount-1];
        email_messages = new string[mailcount-1];
        foreach(XmlNode node1 in xdoc.SelectNodes("feed/entry"))
        {
             ls.Items.Add(node1.SelectSingleNode("title").InnerText);//add to the lisbox 
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); //msg error
}
```

Comment: What does the exception give?

Comment: When you have an error and you ask a question about that error you need to include that error. An error that occurs at runtime this case its called an `Exception` (*this is how errors manifest themselves in .net*). Include the `Message`, the `Type`, the `StackTrace`, and repeat this recursivly across `InnerException`s all the way down. Use the edit link on your question to include that detail, do not include it as a comment. Please also read [How do I ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have problems in this line xdoc.LoadXml(response)